# Why react native fastimage is fetching images even if I enable cacheOnly?

Tags: react-native, react-native-fast-image

According to the documentation of the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image) if you do this:

```js
cache={FastImage.cacheControl.cacheOnly}
```

it should only show images from cache, not make any network requests.

However, I tried to clear cache and re run the app, it still fetches images:

```js
  const cacheImg = profile_pic_url && (<TouchableOpacity ><FastImage
     source={{
        uri: profile_pic_url.url,
        priority: FastImage.priority.high,
     }}
     style={styles.userProfilePic}
     cache={FastImage.cacheControl.cacheOnly}
     resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
  /></TouchableOpacity>);
```

To be sure I even clear in the componentDidMount:

```js
  FastImage.clearMemoryCache();
  FastImage.clearDiskCache();
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?!

Answer (score 1):

According to `documentation`, the `cache prop` should be inside the source as this

```js
const cacheImg = profile_pic_url && (
 <TouchableOpacity>
   <FastImage
     source={{
        uri: profile_pic_url.url,
        priority: FastImage.priority.high,
        cache:'cacheOnly'
     }}
     style={styles.userProfilePic}
     resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
   />
 </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Link - [react-native-fast-image#sourcecache-enum](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image#sourcecache-enum)

Answer (score 0):

If the cache is cleared, there's nothing to fetch locally, so it's forced to fetch the images remotely. I don't think it's possible to tell it not to fetch when there isn't anything in the cache - you would never get your image.

Comment: Why then documentation states that? There is another cache control option called "immutable" and according to their docs it is suppose to fetch from cache if exists and if link changes request from server.

Answer (score 0):

If Memory is big concern for you then try to use Image from react-native directly and remove react-native-fast-image. I was also facing the same issue. Tried with
FastImage.clearMemoryCache();
FastImage.clearDiskCache();

in componentWillUnMount()

It clear lots of memory but my target is not achieving so i simply use Image and its miracle for me.